# histogram fault in base graphics?

Tags: r, graphics, histogram, radix

I wrote the following code to demonstrate a flat statistical distribution:

```
m <- trunc(runif(100000,1,21))  
table(m)  
hist(m)
```

The values from table (m) are as expected:

```
5010 5053 4951 5030 5034 5131 4895 5032 4974 5073 4947 5030 4939 5011 5069  
4910 4992 4990 4946 4983
```

However hist (m) shows twice as many counts in the first bin than expected:

[image: histogram with first cell too large!]

I tried setting breaks: hist (m, breaks = 21) with 20, 21, or other values, but the issue persists.

I think it might have something to do with the "pretty" operator, but having spent an hour working on this, I still can't see how to get an sensible histogram.

Comment: For detailed explanation on how the breaks are calculated you may have a look at [this post](http://planspace.org/20141225-how_does_r_calculate_histogram_break_points/). The process of break calculation starts with `ceiling(log2(length(x)) + 1)` which is later passed to `pretty`, as explained in the linked article.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the correct histogram via

```
hist(m, breaks=0:21)
```

If you look at `?hist` and go to the `breaks` section, you'll come to:

> --snip--
>
> In the last
>   three cases the number is a suggestion only; the breakpoints will be
>   set to pretty values.

i.e. If you want to exactly specify the breaks, you need to give a vector

Comment: Thank you for this, and thank you Konrad.  I was tearing my hair - which is hard because I have hardly any!   ...george...